# Is there a more pythonic way to find the point in a list which is closest to another point?

Tags: python

I have a list of 2d points, and would like to find the one which is closest to a given point. The code (get_closest_point()) below does what I want. But is there a nicer way to do this in python?

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.position = pos


class Point(object):
    ..
    def compute_distance_to(self, p)
        ..

class SomeClient(object):
    ..

    def get_closest_point(self, points, p1):
        closest = (None, float(sys.maxint))
        for p2 in points:
            distance = p2.compute_distance_to(p1) 
            if distance < closest[1]:
                closest = (p2, distance)

        return closest[0]

    def get_closest_circle(self, circles, p1):
        closest = (None, float(sys.maxint))
        for c in circles:
            distance = c.position.compute_distance_to(p1) 
            if distance < closest[1]:
                closest = (c, distance)

        return closest[0]
```

Comment: interesting question. keep implementing some variant of argmax/argmin myself over and over again

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument to the `min()` function:

Edit: after some consideration, this should be a method of your `Point` class, and i'll fix some other obvious deficiencies:

```
class Point(object):
    def get_closest_point(self, points):
        return min(points, key=self.compute_distance_to)
```

or, to do this with a more elaborate case, say a list of instances with a `loc` attribute,

```
min(items, key= lambda item: p1.compute_distance_to(item.loc))
```

and so on

Comment: Good answer! To make it more interesting: what if the list of objects are not points, but rather a list of objects which have a Point member? E.g. a circle with a center point..

Comment: @aaronasterling Close but no cigar: the comparison has to return the object, and not the distance... Thanks, anyway! :)

Comment: Thanks, guys: replaced my code, and all tests are still green! :)

Comment: @Kristian: if your key function just returns the distance, wrap it in a lambda that returns the distance and the object: `key=lambda p:(self.compute_distance_to(p),p)`  Now min works, and you get the distance and the closest point.

Comment: @Paul: The `key` arg is used to compute the sorting weight of the elements in the list.  the return value of `min` is always a member of the list given to it.

Comment: @TMG - you're right, I was thrown off by the earlier comment, but easily confirmed: `min(["abc","d","EFLSKDJ"],key=len)` returns `"d"`, not 1.